# Two zend applications: one in a subdomain, one on root

Tags: zend-framework, subdomain

I'm using Zend for my corporate website. This website contains two seperate applications, namely the website itself (which is a CMS) and the customer panel. The administration panel will be launched on a subdomain, namely customer.domain.com. The website runs on a shared hosting package.

What would be the smartest configuration for this situation?

Thanks,
Martijn

Answer (score 2):

Create the admin panel as a module then use the [Hostname](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname) router to direct the sub-domain requests to it.

Comment: Sorry for my late comment. Thanks for your reply! My CMS uses a 'default' and 'admin' module (website, backend) and my customer panel uses a 'default', 'debtor' and 'admin' (login, debtor, admin) module. I'd like to keep these two applications seperated as much as possible. Would it be possible to create two different 'application' folders, or something?)

Answer (score 0):

I've choosen the following configuration. On domain-level I've created the application folder. This folder contains two folders, namely 'cms' and 'billings'. I've also created a ServerAlias so that the subdomain points to index.php. In index.php I use PHP's $_SERVER HTTP HOST to determine which application needs to be loaded.